# couldn't download table dataset from https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/#/nordic/table

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, data-science, screen-scraping

I am working on my data science homework. I am trying to download the weekly table data by using pyython from : https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/Dayahead/Area-Prices/ALL1/Hourly12/?view=table for my exam.

I have the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
urls = "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/Dayahead/Area-Prices/ALL1/Hourly12/?view=table"
df = pd.read_html('urls')
df
```

I got the following repose:

```
raise ValueError("No tables found")
```

I tried to inspect web console by using beautiful soup. This page have table (html) but i get empty data as a result. So, i tried to check with div then i get a result. That's mean the code is correct but the issue is why it not read table?

Here is my code :

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

for table in soup.find_all('div'):
    print(table.get('class'))

# then i tried to export the data in csv file.
open('export1.csv', 'wb').write(soup.content)
```

Photo of inspection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeH8K.png)

I tried many different solutions that recommend online but still couldn't solve the issue. Appreciate if you can help me download the table, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Chrome Developer Tools / Chrome Inspector. Go to the URL in Chrome and press F12. Open the "Network" Tab. You will see source of the data. You can use that specific URL for getting the specific table data. Your current method gets the entire page HTML, not just the table.

After that you can download the data using Python requests library.
I can see in the Network tab that the data is being fetched from this URL:

```
https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/api/marketdata/page/12?currency=,,,EUR
```

In order to use requests library, you need to install it using:

```
pip install requests
```

You may have to use pip3 instead of pip depending upon your system/platform.

Then get data from the table using:

```
import requests
data = requests.get("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/api/marketdata/page/12?currency=,,,EUR")
print(data.json())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. It' work perfectly  on python but I need to download  hourly data of each day. I  still couldn't find the URL link for that information